# Локальный импорт запрещён?

Tags: python

Добрых суток. Всегда считал, что локальный импорт(в теле функции) - это нормально и естественно, но сегодня мне сказали, что это очень плохой стиль и может вызвать проблемы.

Описана ли такая возможность в PEP8 или в google-style? Можно ссылку? Я не нашёл. Видел только упоминания, что импорты должны быть в начале модуля, сразу после документации.

Comment: Лично я тоже считаю, _"что это очень плохой стиль и может вызвать проблемы."_ Вот соответствующий пункт `PEP`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id23.

Comment: nomnoms12, там речь не касается локальных импортов, только лишь как импортировать.

Comment: Цитирую: _"Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants."_. Вольный перевод: "Импорты **ВСЕГДА** помещаются в верхнюю часть файла, сразу после любых комментариев к модулям и строк документации, а также перед глобальными переменными модуля и константами.". Всегда в моём понимании означает, что любые другие ситуации (например, локальный импорт) исключаются.

Comment: @nomnoms12, тем не менее про локальный импорт там ни слова.